# Multiple mysql statements putting data in to the same table

Tags: mysql

i have a sql statement that looks like this.

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
SELECT Op_Number, Machine_Number, Format(SUM(Elapsed),2) AS Elapsed , SUM(Count) AS Count , SUM(Scrap) AS Scrap , (SUM(`Scrap`)/SUM(`Count`)) * 100 AS ScrapPercent 
FROM count_down 
WHERE Wo_Number != 'PlaceHolder' AND Count > 0
Group BY Op_Number , Machine_Number
 LIMIT 5
) AS tmp_table ORDER BY Machine_Number, Count desc;
```

This query returns a result that looks like:

```
OP_number | Machine_Number | Elapsed | Count | Scrap | ScrapPerent 
 --------------------------------------------------------------------
  Value1  |     1          |   20     |  10  |  10   |   100
  Value2  |     10         |   30     |  5   |   0   |    0
```

However when i have alot of rows for each machine so for example if there are 200 records for machine 1 and 200 for machine 10 i would have 400 records in this result set, so what i want to do it limit this statement to 5 and ad a WHERE so,  Where Machine_number = 1,

So in the end what i would like is for a query that works like this

```
//Query for machine1
SELECT * FROM ( 
SELECT Op_Number, Machine_Number, Format(SUM(Elapsed),2) AS Elapsed , SUM(Count) AS Count , SUM(Scrap) AS Scrap , (SUM(`Scrap`)/SUM(`Count`)) * 100 AS ScrapPercent 
FROM count_down 
WHERE Wo_Number != 'PlaceHolder' AND Count > 0 AND Machine_number = 1
Group BY Op_Number , Machine_Number
 LIMIT 5
) AS tmp_table ORDER BY Machine_Number, Count desc;

// Query for machine 2 
  SELECT * FROM ( 
 SELECT Op_Number, Machine_Number, Format(SUM(Elapsed),2) AS Elapsed , SUM(Count) AS Count , SUM(Scrap) AS Scrap , (SUM(`Scrap`)/SUM(`Count`)) * 100 AS ScrapPercent 
FROM count_down 
WHERE Wo_Number != 'PlaceHolder' AND Count > 0 AND Machine_number = 2
Group BY Op_Number , Machine_Number
 LIMIT 5
) AS tmp_table ORDER BY Machine_Number, Count desc;
```

Ext ext fyi there would be 14 machines in the full set and then i want the results to look like this

```
    OP_number | Machine_Number | Elapsed | Count | Scrap | ScrapPerent 
 --------------------------------------------------------------------
  Value1  |     1          |   20     |  10  |  10   |   100
  Value1  |     1          |   20     |  10  |  10   |   100
  Value1  |     1          |   20     |  10  |  10   |   100
  Value1  |     1          |   20     |  10  |  10   |   100
  Value1  |     1          |   20     |  10  |  10   |   100
  Value1  |     2          |   20     |  10  |  10   |   100
  Value1  |     2          |   20     |  10  |  10   |   100
  Value1  |     2          |   20     |  10  |  10   |   100
  Value1  |     2          |   20     |  10  |  10   |   100
  Value1  |     2          |   20     |  10  |  10   |   100
  Value1  |     3          |   20     |  10  |  10   |   100
  Value1  |     3          |   20     |  10  |  10   |   100
  Value1  |     3          |   20     |  10  |  10   |   100
  Value1  |     3          |   20     |  10  |  10   |   100
  Value1  |     3          |   20     |  10  |  10   |   100
```

Here is an sqlfiddle of what i have so far

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d737e2/1

So as you can see from this fiddle, i am getting the results for machine 10 and limiting it to 5 results as to only get the top 5, what i want to do is this query but for 14 machines so insted of machine 1

```
Where Machine_number = 1;
Where Machine_number = 2;  
Where Machine_number = 3;
ext ext
```

And then return the results like shown above, but each query for that machine needs to be limited to 5 results